# how to extract a zero-dimensional slice from a 1-dimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, slice, matrix-indexing

Is there a way to slice a zero-dimensional sub-array from a 1-dimensional array?

For example, if I have a N-dimensional `ndarray` `arr`, `arr[0]` returns a (N-1)-dimensional `ndarray`.

However, if I have a 1-dimensional `ndarray` `x`, `x[0]` doesn't return a 0-dimensional ndarray, but rather a `numpy.int64`, (if `x` contains `int64`s).

Minimal example:

```
def increment(zero_d_array):
    zero_d_array[...] = zero_d_array + 1

counter = numpy.array(0)  # a zero-dimensional array containing scalar 0
increment(counter)        # success; counter is now 1

counters = numpy.zeros(3, dtype=int)  # [0, 0, 0]
increment(counter[1])    # fails; counter[1] is a numpy.int64, not a 0-D array
```

I realize the above would work with `increment(counter[1:2])`, but only because `increment()` happens to work with both 0-D and 1-D inputs. Not all functions will be so flexible.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way.  Zero-d arrays are a bit of an oddity in Numpy.  Is there a reason you actually need to do this?

Comment: I often find zero-d arrays to be a useful way of having "boxed" primitives, like an int I can pass to a function to have it modified in-place (something you can't do with plain ints). As I mention in the question, obviously there are workarounds like using size-1 1-D slices instead, but these are more verbose.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is do you need to be able to get them by slicing?  If you just want to keep a zero-d counter around, you can do it as you showed by creating it explicitly.  So what I mean is, what are you actually doing that makes you want to generically slice and increment arrays of any dimension, instead of just making your counter and incrementing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an ellipsis:

```
increment(counter[1, ...])
```